# Age of RTK corrections - fixed solution accuracy

Tags: gps, atmospheric-correction, rtklib

Does anyone know how the age of NTRIP corrections influences accuracy of an RTK solution?

I read somewhere that correction loss for few seconds or even a minute may still be acceptable for some applications. I ask this because I live in Europe where we have a nice dense CORS network equivalent but most countries charge a fee for its usage based on time. So one could save quite some money by asking for corrections less frequently (maybe every 10 seconds or even less, given that payments units are seconds).

I found one post with vertical test (unknown agricultural-grade setup): http://lefebure.com/articles/rtk-correction-data-age-accuracy/

I am interested in horizontal accuracy for a L1 and L1/L2 GNSS RTK setup.

Answer (score 2):

I have experience using RTK NTRIP corrections in the field, ideally, corrections should be less than 3 seconds depending on the application. Fixes every 10 seconds will be compromised depending on the application and your equipment, usually fixed status is lost with 20 seconds. Professionally surveyors avoid using older than 10 seconds, this ensures the reliability of the fix.